# Lotus Notes - Copy sent emails to other folder

Tags: email, lotus-notes, email-filter

Using Lotus Notes, I would like to move/copy all sent emails to particular customers to specified folder for that customer.  I have tried building filter rules.

```
When
 Internet Domain contains example.com
Or To or CC contains example.com
Move To Vendor\Example
```

This Rule will move Incoming Mail but not Sent. Can this be done with a filter rule or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Lotus Notes' mail rules only operate on incoming mail, not on mail that is being sent.

You could write an agent that looks at all new or modified documents in your mail database, determines whether those document are sent messages, and takes action on them. Getting that agent to run automatically on the Domino mail server will require permissions that your organization may not want to give you. Running locally on your own computer is possible, but setting it up to run automatically could be problematic so you might have to settle for triggering it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Minds up!
The Sent view is not a Folder, it's a View. 
That means:

- Removing mails from that view removes them from your mail file!
- You can "add" mails you mark in then Sent view to a folder of your choice, but not "move" them to that folder.
  (You can do that for new mails while sending them by clicking "Send and Save" button)